# Change volume of own process in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to change the volume of my own process:

[image]

I have tried this method:

```
public static void SetApplicationVolume(string name, float level)
{
    ISimpleAudioVolume volume = GetVolumeObject(name);
    if (volume == null)
        return;

    Guid guid = Guid.Empty;
    volume.SetMasterVolume(level / 100, ref guid);
}

private static ISimpleAudioVolume GetVolumeObject(string name)
{
    // get the speakers (1st render + multimedia) device
    IMMDeviceEnumerator deviceEnumerator = (IMMDeviceEnumerator)(new MMDeviceEnumerator());
    IMMDevice speakers;
    deviceEnumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia, out speakers);

    // activate the session manager. we need the enumerator
    Guid IID_IAudioSessionManager2 = typeof(IAudioSessionManager2).GUID;
    object o;
    speakers.Activate(ref IID_IAudioSessionManager2, 0, IntPtr.Zero, out o);
    IAudioSessionManager2 mgr = (IAudioSessionManager2)o;

    // enumerate sessions for on this device
    IAudioSessionEnumerator sessionEnumerator;
    mgr.GetSessionEnumerator(out sessionEnumerator);
    int count;
    sessionEnumerator.GetCount(out count);

    // search for an audio session with the required name
    // NOTE: we could also use the process id instead of the app name (with IAudioSessionControl2)
    ISimpleAudioVolume volumeControl = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        IAudioSessionControl ctl;
        sessionEnumerator.GetSession(i, out ctl);
        string dn;
        ctl.GetDisplayName(out dn);
        if (string.Compare(name, dn, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
        {
            volumeControl = ctl as ISimpleAudioVolume;
            break;
        }
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ctl);
    }
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sessionEnumerator);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mgr);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(speakers);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(deviceEnumerator);
    return volumeControl;
}
```

and it gives me error:

> ISimpleAudioVolume, IAudioSessionEnumerator ... is inaccessible due to
> it's protection level

is there another way to do this?

Comment: In general, just change all `private` to `public` for your declarations of the support structures needed to use that API.